# Command Line Args in VS Code (Mac) Create New File Instead of Running Command

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run a command such as `code -h` in terminal, a new file named "-h" is created and opened in VS Code instead of running the "help" command. The same results for similar optional commands, such as `code -v` and `code --help`.

- VSCode Version: 1.20.1
- OS Version:OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
- Shell: zsh

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open terminal
2. run `code -h`

Here is what I put in source file (~/.zshrc)

```
### VS Code
code () {
if [[ $# = 0 ]]
then
    open -a "Visual Studio Code"
else
    [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
    open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
fi
}
```

Here is what I put in ~/.zprofile

```
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```